# Time complexity for insertion and search in B+ tree

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I am trying to test out the implementation of B+ tree against various values of m. All the resources say the time complexity of insert and search is `O(logn) base m` where n is number of keys and m is the order. If that is the case, as the order `m` increases with n being constant, the times for both insert and search should come down.
I tested an implementation of B+ tree with 100,000 keys and varied the order from `5-100`. Following were the results in `milliseconds`. For each value of `m`, I am doing a fresh creation of tree with 100,000 keys insertion and recording total time for that. Then, I am doing search for 100 valid queries and recording total time for that.

```
M=5    InsertTime: 810    SearchTime:2
M=6    InsertTime: 748    SearchTime:0
M=7    InsertTime: 670    SearchTime:0
M=8    InsertTime: 689    SearchTime:0
M=9    InsertTime: 550    SearchTime:0
M=10    InsertTime: 591    SearchTime:0
M=11    InsertTime: 597    SearchTime:0
M=12    InsertTime: 414    SearchTime:0
M=13    InsertTime: 542    SearchTime:0
M=14    InsertTime: 522    SearchTime:0
M=15    InsertTime: 521    SearchTime:0
M=16    InsertTime: 553    SearchTime:1
M=17    InsertTime: 677    SearchTime:0
M=18    InsertTime: 570    SearchTime:0
M=19    InsertTime: 542    SearchTime:0
M=20    InsertTime: 459    SearchTime:0
M=21    InsertTime: 1238    SearchTime:0
M=22    InsertTime: 885    SearchTime:0
M=23    InsertTime: 450    SearchTime:0
M=24    InsertTime: 369    SearchTime:1
M=25    InsertTime: 371    SearchTime:0
M=26    InsertTime: 398    SearchTime:0
M=27    InsertTime: 383    SearchTime:0
M=28    InsertTime: 374    SearchTime:0
M=29    InsertTime: 516    SearchTime:0
M=30    InsertTime: 363    SearchTime:0
M=31    InsertTime: 347    SearchTime:0
M=32    InsertTime: 496    SearchTime:0
M=33    InsertTime: 429    SearchTime:0
M=34    InsertTime: 383    SearchTime:0
M=35    InsertTime: 520    SearchTime:0
M=36    InsertTime: 492    SearchTime:0
M=37    InsertTime: 418    SearchTime:0
M=38    InsertTime: 527    SearchTime:0
M=39    InsertTime: 557    SearchTime:0
M=40    InsertTime: 472    SearchTime:0
M=41    InsertTime: 534    SearchTime:0
M=42    InsertTime: 588    SearchTime:0
M=43    InsertTime: 536    SearchTime:0
M=44    InsertTime: 538    SearchTime:0
M=45    InsertTime: 597    SearchTime:0
M=46    InsertTime: 1055    SearchTime:0
M=47    InsertTime: 937    SearchTime:0
M=48    InsertTime: 972    SearchTime:0
M=49    InsertTime: 1400    SearchTime:0
M=50    InsertTime: 1210    SearchTime:0
M=51    InsertTime: 1016    SearchTime:0
M=52    InsertTime: 995    SearchTime:0
M=53    InsertTime: 1202    SearchTime:0
M=54    InsertTime: 963    SearchTime:0
M=55    InsertTime: 894    SearchTime:0
M=56    InsertTime: 1143    SearchTime:0
M=57    InsertTime: 2299    SearchTime:0
M=58    InsertTime: 1259    SearchTime:0
M=59    InsertTime: 2315    SearchTime:0
M=60    InsertTime: 734    SearchTime:0
M=61    InsertTime: 747    SearchTime:0
M=62    InsertTime: 915    SearchTime:0
M=63    InsertTime: 1048    SearchTime:0
M=64    InsertTime: 923    SearchTime:0
M=65    InsertTime: 791    SearchTime:0
M=66    InsertTime: 805    SearchTime:0
M=67    InsertTime: 935    SearchTime:0
M=68    InsertTime: 1072    SearchTime:0
M=69    InsertTime: 873    SearchTime:0
M=70    InsertTime: 819    SearchTime:0
M=71    InsertTime: 789    SearchTime:0
M=72    InsertTime: 917    SearchTime:0
M=73    InsertTime: 1004    SearchTime:1
M=74    InsertTime: 941    SearchTime:0
M=75    InsertTime: 935    SearchTime:0
M=76    InsertTime: 1250    SearchTime:0
M=77    InsertTime: 1426    SearchTime:0
M=78    InsertTime: 1549    SearchTime:0
M=79    InsertTime: 1646    SearchTime:0
M=80    InsertTime: 1464    SearchTime:0
M=81    InsertTime: 1377    SearchTime:0
M=82    InsertTime: 1075    SearchTime:0
M=83    InsertTime: 1175    SearchTime:0
M=84    InsertTime: 1611    SearchTime:0
M=85    InsertTime: 2179    SearchTime:0
M=86    InsertTime: 1691    SearchTime:0
M=87    InsertTime: 2959    SearchTime:0
M=88    InsertTime: 958    SearchTime:0
M=89    InsertTime: 942    SearchTime:0
M=90    InsertTime: 903    SearchTime:0
M=91    InsertTime: 925    SearchTime:0
M=92    InsertTime: 1022    SearchTime:0
M=93    InsertTime: 940    SearchTime:0
M=94    InsertTime: 1057    SearchTime:0
M=95    InsertTime: 1168    SearchTime:0
M=96    InsertTime: 1195    SearchTime:0
M=97    InsertTime: 1225    SearchTime:0
M=98    InsertTime: 1173    SearchTime:0
M=99    InsertTime: 1081    SearchTime:0
M=100    InsertTime: 1059    SearchTime:0
```

From, the results above my the time complexity doesnt seem to be correct. If we see the insertion time, it goes up and down randomly whereas the search time more or less lies between 0-3 milli seconds which is again weird.